# What do you call a person who asks for an appointment and the person who was asked?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

> Andrew wants to make an appointment with Sally but Sally needs to determine 
>       whether the time Andrew stated is suitable for her.

What do you call Andrew and Sally? I found words like a*ppointee, appointer, subject* but they all don't seem to fit.

I think Sally may be called *object* but I'm not sure about Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the general terms ***inviter*** and ***invitee***, or ***requester*** and ***invitee***.

I wouldn't use ***appointer*** and ***appointee***, as these terms refer to the appointment of positions (like Cabinet Secretaries and such). Your question seems more concerned with the setting of meetings.

Comment: But who is inviting whom? If Sally were inviting Andrew, she would have already checked whether she will be available at that time. If Andrew is "making an appointment with" Sally, he is _inviting himself_ to meet with her.

Comment: In Google calendar, the term **organizer** is used for the proposer of the meeting, and **guest** for the person that responds. These are probably as good as anything.